# DataBinding with read-only property

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, uwp

I have a view that allows the user to enter a payment amount, then optionally enter principal, interest, and escrow amounts.

Everything is good with those four `TextBox`es using `TwoWay` databinding like so:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Text="Payment Amount" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="3"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentPayment.PaymentAmount, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:N}', Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="4"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Text="Principal" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="4"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Width="100" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentPayment.PrincipalAmount, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:N}', Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="5"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Text="Interest" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="5"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Width="100"
         MaxLength="20"
         Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentPayment.InterestAmount, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:N}', Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Row="6"
           Grid.Column="0"
           Text="Escrow" />
<TextBox Grid.Row="6"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Width="100"
         MaxLength="20"
         Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentPayment.EscrowAmount, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:N}', Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

However, when I try to add a "summary" property called `TotalAmount` that takes the total of `PrincipalAmount`+`InterestAmount`+`EscrowAmount` as shown here:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public decimal TotalAmount
{
    get
    {
        var amount = EscrowAmount + InterestAmount + PrincipalAmount;
        return amount;
    }
}
```

My property does not update if the user makes changes to the `TextBox` for principal/interest/escrow amounts. The `TotalAmount` displays correctly when loading the view, but does not update when the values change. Here is the XAML for the `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentPayment.TotalAmount, Converter={StaticResource StringFormatConverter}, ConverterParameter='{}{0:N}'}" />
```

Is there a way to let the `TotalAmount` property know when one of the other properties' value changes, so it can update the displayed value?

**EDIT**

Adding the other three property definitions to show use of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

```
private decimal _principalAmount;
[JsonProperty("principalamount")]
public decimal PrincipalAmount
{
    get { return _principalAmount; }
    set { Set(ref _principalAmount, value); }
}

private decimal _escrowAmount;
[JsonProperty("escrowamount")]
public decimal EscrowAmount
{
    get { return _escrowAmount; }
    set { Set(ref _escrowAmount, value); }
}

private decimal _interestAmount;
[JsonProperty("interestamount")]
public decimal InterestAmount
{
    get { return _interestAmount; }
    set { Set(ref _interestAmount, value); }
}
```

`Set` is a method from Template 10's `BindableBase`:

```
public abstract class BindableBase : IBindable, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected BindableBase();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null);
    public virtual void RaisePropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression);
    public virtual bool Set<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null);
    public virtual bool Set<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression, ref T field, T newValue);
}
```

**EDIT**

The main issue I was having was due to the different behavior of compiled bindings. The default `Mode` is `OneTime`, which is different from the standard binding default of `OneWay`. Once I raised the property change notifications to the `TotalValue` property, I still had to change the binding mode to `OneWay` to get my UI to update.

More information about standard bindings and compiled bindings can be found at [x:Bind markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/x-bind-markup-extension)

Comment: See, in your example, when one of those other three properties is being set, property `TotalAmount` is not notified, therefore the UI is not updated. ;)

Comment: Should I add a notification in each setter to notify `TotalAmount`??

Comment: Yes, like I have told you in my answer.

Comment: That is different. Your answer shows `PrincipalAmount` raising property changed event on `PrincipalAmount`. My properties already notify when they are updated (inside the `Set()` method from Template 10's `BindableBase`

Comment: Sorry, my bad, that was what I meant, I corrected my answer. It should update `TotalAmount`, like it does now. The `PrincipalAmount` is of course notified automatically by your Set method. I got distracted by your property names.

Comment: So, in your case, you should use `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(TotalAmount))` inside every setter of those three properties, and that is it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your model class (Payment) should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and raise `PropertyChanged` event for property `TotalAmount` when one of those three properties change.

And make sure that you raise `PropertyChanged` for `TotalAmount` after you set the new value, otherwise it will not update the `TotalAmount` with the latest values, which is probably not what you want.

Example:

```
Payment : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private decimal _principalAmount;
    public decimal PrincipalAmount
    {
        get { return _principalAmount; }
        set
        {
            _principalAmount = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(PrincipalAmount));

            // lets the design know that property "TotalAmount" should also be updated ...
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(TotalAmount));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The other three properties all implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I assumed that they would update the `TotalAmount` property when one of them changed. I will add the other three properties to my question.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` should implement the model class, not the property class. Look at my example above.

Comment: In addition to the `RaisePropertyChanged`, I also had to add set the `Mode=OneWay`. Apparently the default for `x:Bind` was defaulting to `Mode=OneTime`.

Comment: I see. That is why I always explicitly set the binding mode. :)

Comment: It tricked me too, because I had previously tried explicitly setting the binding to `OneWay`, but that was before I had added the `RaisePropertyChanged` as you suggested in your answer.